Why typescript can't accept a string for class-variance-authority type?
Here's my Button using class-variance-authority
const buttonVariants = cva('...',
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        a: '...',
        b: '...',
        c: '...',
      }
    },
    defaultVariants: { variant: 'a' }
  } 
);

export type ButtonProps = {
  label: string;
  ...
} & VariantProps<typeof buttonVariants>;


export default function Button({ variant }: ButtonProps) {
  ...
}

Then in my page I want to use it this way :
const typeA = 1;
const typeB = 2;
const typeC = 3;

const variants: { [key: number]: string } = {
  [typeA]: 'a',
  [typeB]: 'b',
  [typeC]: 'c',
};

return (
  <div class="flex gap-2">
    {buttons.map((button) => (
      <Button variant={variants[button.type]} />
    ))}
  </div>
)

And I have a typescript error with "variant" underlined with this message :

Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c" | undefined'.


Get rid of { [key: number]: string }

…and add as const instead

OK... Can someone explain to me why adding  as const fixed my problem ?
